# How to apply changes to two different input field with one function

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm creating a performance comparing widget in Angular. It will compare performance of this Calendar year with Previous Calendar Year and this Year-to-date with Previous Year-to-date. I'll take care of all those mathematics. I've created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5rajnb) also. But let me explain the code also. I have created two dropdowns using simple HTML `select` and `option` tags. And I've one more component `app-monthpicker`. This is what I mean:

[image]

Both dropdowns are reading options from same array in typescript:

```
modes = ['Calendar Year', 'Year to date'];
```

And then there is a predefined range for each option.

1. For Calendar year, range is '01-01-2020 to 12-31-2020';
2. For Year-to-date, range is '01-01-2020 to 02-07-2020';

These ranges are set in `app-monthpicker`. Let them be hard-coded.

Now, both the dropdowns are bound with same variable. Here's the code:

```html
<div class="inner-panel">
  <h3>Time selection widget</h3>
  Primary:<br>
  <select [(ngModel)]="primaryMode" (change)="modeChangeHandler($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let mode of modes" [ngValue]="mode">{{mode}}</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <app-monthpicker></app-monthpicker>
  <br><br>
  Secondary:<br>
  <select [(ngModel)]="secondaryMode" (change)="modeChangeHandler($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let mode of modes" [ngValue]="mode">Previous {{mode}}</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <app-monthpicker></app-monthpicker>
</div>
```

and here's my method `modeChangeHandler`:

```
@ViewChild(MonthpickerComponent, {static: false}) monthpicker: MonthpickerComponent;

constructor() {}

ngOnInit(): void {
}

modeChangeHandler() {
    if (this.primaryMode === this.modes[0] || this.secondaryMode === this.modes[0]) {
        this.initCalendarYear();
    } else if (this.primaryMode === this.modes[1] || this.secondaryMode === this.modes[1]) {
        this.initYearToDate();
    } else {
      console.log("Default case");
    }
}

initCalendarYear() {
    this.monthpicker.startRange = '01-01-2020';
    this.monthpicker.endRange = '12-31-2020';
}

initYearToDate() {
    this.monthpicker.startRange = '01-01-2020';
    this.monthpicker.endRange = '02-07-2020';
}
```

My problem is that my Second dropdown is not changing the values even though they are bounded to same variables. It is still changing the range of above input field and not its own.

Comment: Hello Tanzeel, I think it would be easier if you could provide a stackblitz or something where people can see an minimum working example

Comment: You have different `[(ngModel)]` for both drop downs so changing one won't reflect an instant change in other.

Comment: It is already there. I mentioned in the question also. :)

Comment: @rmjoia. It is already there. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5rajnb

Comment: @Mridul. But in my `modeChangeHandler` method I'm changing both of them.

Comment: If i select primary, secondary should also have same `mode` value?

Comment: `monthpicker` is only the *first* component, did you want all [`ViewChildren`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren)?

Comment: I think that you're just referencing the first month picker.. and regardless of which drop down you select, you only change the first. The viewChild is referencing only one component, and that's the one it's changed, and works for both dropdowns, you just have to reference the second and use it, not sure if having one event handler for both will be the best option in such case

Comment: @rmjoia, I wanted two different handlers but my tech lead said, "No you do it with one generic method only". So In my method I'm setting both the modes i.e. primaryMode and secondaryMode.

Comment: yeah, but the target you update, the `this.monthpicker`is always the first...

Comment: Can you please edit my stackblitz. I'm didn't understand very well.

Comment: @rmjoia, so that means even if create two separate handlers for both, the problem will still be there.

Comment: tbh.. I'm not sure of what you want.. but check this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zfyfog), I have a reference of the two month pickers and I'm updating both, not only the first.. but as I said, I'm not following what you want to do.. if you want to update them independently, you have to "figure out" which drop down was selected and update the monthpicker

Comment: @Tanzeel I changed it a bit now.. so you have one event handler and now each select (primary or secondary) changes only their monthPicker.. is this what you wanted?

Comment: @rmjoia. This is exactly what i wanted. Can you please post this as an answer for me to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use the Angular template syntax and Ids

I added `#primary` and `#secondary` to the monthPickers to specify which one was it and so I can reference them from the component and added an id to both the selectors, which I will use to identify the target of the event when triggered.

```
<div class="time-selector">
<p-overlayPanel class="my-overlay" #op>
    <br />
    <div class="inner-panel">
        <h3>Time selection widget</h3>
        Primary:<br>
        <select id="primarySelect" [(ngModel)]="primaryMode" (change)="modeChangeHandler($event)">
           <option *ngFor="let mode of modes" [ngValue]="mode">{{mode}}</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <app-monthpicker #primary></app-monthpicker>
        <br><br>
        Secondary:<br>
        <select id="secondarySelect" [(ngModel)]="secondaryMode" (change)="modeChangeHandler($event)">
           <option *ngFor="let mode of modes" [ngValue]="mode">Previous {{mode}}</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <app-monthpicker #secondary></app-monthpicker>
    </div>
</p-overlayPanel>
```

and on the component I made the following changes:

replaced the viewChild with:

```
 @ViewChild("primary", { static: true }) primaryMonthPicker: MonthpickerComponent;
 @ViewChild("secondary", { static: true }) secondaryMonthPicker: MonthpickerComponent;
```

and updated the event handler and functions called, passing the target id to identify which calendar to update.

```
 modeChangeHandler(event) {
    if (
      this.primaryMode === this.modes[0] ||
      this.secondaryMode === this.modes[0]
    ) {
      this.initCalendarYear(event.target.id);
    } else if (this.primaryMode === this.modes[1]) {
      this.initYearToDate(event.target.id);
    } else {
      console.log("Default case");
    }
  }

  initCalendarYear(target: string) {
    if (target === "primarySelect") {
      this.secondaryMonthPicker.startRange = "01-01-2020";
      this.primaryMonthPicker.endRange = "12-31-2020";
    } else if (target === "secondarySelect") {
      this.primaryMonthPicker.startRange = "01-01-2020";
      this.secondaryMonthPicker.endRange = "12-31-2020";
    }
  }

  initYearToDate(target: string) {
    if (target === "primarySelect") {
      this.primaryMonthPicker.startRange = "01-01-2020";
      this.primaryMonthPicker.endRange = "02-07-2020";
    } else if (target === "secondarySelect") {
      this.secondaryMonthPicker.startRange = "01-01-2020";
      this.secondaryMonthPicker.endRange = "02-07-2020";
    }
  }
```

Full example available @ [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zfyfog)

Comment: This is perfect. Got my answer.